# How do I call static variable in a separate class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, scope

How can I access a static variable in a separate class in PHP? Is the scope resolution operator the wrong tool for the job? Example:

```
class DB {
  static $conn = 'Connection';
}



class User {
  function __construct() {
    DB::conn; //throws "Undefined class constant 'conn' error.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DB::$conn
```

You need the $ before the variable name if it's a property.

Comment: Ha, I need to call it a day. Switching between C# and PHP is making me totally overlook pesky missing $ signs! Thanks for the quick catch dirtside!